# How do I set the border colour of my TextView programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to change the border colour of my `TextView` programmatically, depending on the `if` condition in my activity. Here's my `ViewContact.java` code:

```
if (bob == 0) {
  //change colour depending on value

  LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat
      .getDrawable(ViewContact.this,R.drawable.textboxes);
  GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
      .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.textbox_shape);
  gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#DA850B")); // change color
}

if (bob == 1) {

  LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat
      .getDrawable(ViewContact.this,R.drawable.textboxes);
  GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
      .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.textbox_shape);
  gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0A7FDA")); // change color

}

if (bob == 2) {

etc...

}
```

I've looked here [Changing color in a shape inside a layer-list programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705992/changing-color-in-a-shape-inside-a-layer-list-programmatically) and here [Android change color stroke (border) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512013/android-change-color-stroke-border-programmatically) and elsewhere for a solution but can't get it working.

Here is the `xml` for my `TextView` in the `ViewContact.java` activity, `activity_view_contact.xml`:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/textboxes"
            />
```

And here is `textboxes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--space between each text box-->
    <item
        android:top="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textbox_shape"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!--formatting of colour inside the box-->
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <!--formatting of lines on the box-->
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                 />
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <!--text formatting in the box-->
            <padding
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:top="15dp"
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="20dp"
                android:right="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489442/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod Looked at it. But I `cannot resolve symbol` with this line, the name of my `textView` : `categoryname.setBackground(layerDrawable);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the color of the drawable that you load but not the one used in the `TextView`. Add the following line to your code to set the background drawable in the `TextView`:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView1).setBackground(layerDrawable);
```

You can also get the background for the `TextView` directly with

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) findViewById(R.id.textView1).getBackground();
```

Here is a set of code to change the background and the stroke color:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) findViewById(R.id.textView1).getBackground();
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
    .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.textbox_shape);
// Change background color
gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#DA850B"));
// Change stroke color. (Assumes 5px stroke width.)
gradientDrawable.setStroke(5, Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

Comment: @CHarris What isn't working? Are you getting an error or is something happening/not happening?

Comment: I am getting the message, `Cannot resolve symbol 'layerDrawable'` when I try `findViewById(R.id.textView1).setBackground(layerDrawable);`

Answer (score 2):

## TextView - add border in XML or code

Steps for Android Studio 3.5.2 - app running on Android 9 Pie

### Create new drawable

- in project tree
- open **res** folder
- open **drawable folder**
- Right click on drawable
- Choose **New** > **Drawable resource file**
- New resource screen appears
- enter name
- textview_border.xml
- leave all other options alone
- Press **Ok**

#### Creates default drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</selector>
```

#### Replace the root < selector > with this < shape />.. xml but keep exact name space generated by Android Studio - if different from below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--FILL    -->
    <solid android:color="#fafbfb" />

    <!--    BORDER-->
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

### You can now use this drawable shape as a background

Given any textview

Here we set the background color to Android system color white in XML

```
android:background="@android:color/white"

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="SOME TEXT"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAppColorAppDark0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_textSize_mediumToSmall"
       .../>
```

Now we can use the drawable instead

```
android:background="@drawable/textview_border"

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:text="SOME TEXT"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAppColorAppDark0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_textSize_mediumToSmall"
       ..layout commands etc./>
```

Or you can add it programatically

```
TextView textView1 = activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//see res/drawable/textview_border.xml
textView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_border);
```

#### Set background to drawable in XML - Design Mode

- In Design mode
- List item
- Click on your textView
- Find background in Declared Attributes or scroll down to All Attributes to add it.
- In the far right of the row click the small bar to the right of the field
- background chooser screen appears
- On left choose type : Drawable instead of Color
- Find textview_border
- Press OK

[image]

Sets the 
android:background="@drawable/textview_border"

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixture_list_constraintlayout_textView_fixturetypecode"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_textSize_mediumToSmall"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to change Stroke color (Border):

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)btn_submit.getBackground();
gradientDrawable.setStroke(2, Color.GREEN);
```

it works.. check it once..

Comment: I am trying this but doesn't work, there is no change: `gradientDrawable.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#DA850B")); `

Comment: try this.. get it from colors.m=xml..
getResources().getColor(R.color.<name_of_color>)--
            --Color.parseColor("#DA850B")); -- For TextViews or Buttons or EditTexts..